# WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2270' ('MQRC_NO_DESTINATIONS_AVAILABLE')

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting this error message when I am trying to post message to the queue using the alias name. It is working fine when I am using the queue manager name and this issue is not occurring to all the alias names. The alias name and the queue name is already defined.

Please let me know in what are all the scenarios this error message can occur.

Comment: Is this a cluster setup?  Have you verified the amqrrmfa cluster repository process is still running on all of the qmgrs?  What version of MQ are you using?

Comment: You need to tell us if this is a cluster and whether the alias is local to the QMgr to which you are connected or if it is advertised to the cluster and remote.  If all you give us is the error code, all you get back is pointers to the manual for that code.  Give us QMgr names and the objects defined on each that are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [IBM documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q043020_.htm) indicates that this occurs when a queue is no longer available and describes the solution as:

```
Check the queue definition and queue status to determine why all instances of the queue 
were removed from the cluster.
```

I would check on the queue definitions again.